# Eureka get self instance

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka

I'm using Spring-Eureka for microservice discovery. I just implemented this bit and I want to maintain other parts of the system before I fully switch to service discovery.

The services published their host address which was configured by `JAVA_OPTS`. Now I wanted to publish what the Eureka client publishes. It is publishing a resolved IP address and the port. How can I get the application info for self from Eureka client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Value("http://${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${server.port}")`

That works. Hostname resolved by spring cloud and the application port should be the same as what would Eureka publishes.